# How to install multiple Tensorflow versions?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia-docker

I'm trying to run the code from this repository: https://github.com/danielgordon10/thor-iqa-cvpr-2018

It has the following requirements

- Python 3.5
- CUDA 8 or 9
- cuDNN
- Tensorflow 1.4 or 1.5
- Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04
- an installation of [darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/tree/yolov3)

My system satisfies neither of these. I don't want to reinstall tf/cuda/cudnn on my machine (especially if have to do that everytime I try to run deep learning code with different tensorflow requirements everytime).

I'm looking for a way to install the requirements and run the code regardless of the host.
To my knowledge that is exactly what Docker is for.

Looking into this there exist docker images from nvidia. For example one called "nvidia/cuda:9.1-cudnn7-runtime". Based on the name I assumed that any image build with this as the base comes with cuda installed. This does not seem to be the case as if I try to install darknet it will fail with the error that "cuda_runtime.h" is missing.

So what my question basicaly boils down to is: How do I keep multiple different versions of cuda and tensorflow on the same machine ? Ideally with docker (or similar) so I won't have to do the process to many times.

It feels like I'm missing and/or don't understand something obvious, because I can't imagine that it can be so hard to run tensorflow code with different versions without reinstalling things from scratch all the time.

Comment: Have you considered creating a virtual environment in the docker, installing the necessary versions, and then activating it ?

Comment: For what purpose would I need the environment ? Isn't docker itself more or less a virtual environment ? To me that sounds like it would just add a second layer

Comment: umm no. docker is NOT a virtual environment. a docker, if anything is analogous to a virtual machine. It contains a complete OS instance with the flexibility to install anything you want on it. Right now, your docker maybe (let's say) *a Linux system that has a version of TensorFlow.*. That python interpreter is the base one that's running on that OS. If you want another TensorFlow installed simultaneously, you would have to set up a virtual environment with the TensorFlow, which now causes python to point to a new interpreter with this different versions of tf.